# Custom Control with Icon Property alike in AppBarButton

Tags: xaml, uwp, windows-10-universal

In UWP the *AppBarButton* has an *Icon* Property. You can put any kind of *IconElement* in there or you can just type a symbol name and intellisence will show you the list of available symbols.

[image]

I want to make a control that would also have an *IconElement* that behaves in the same way (type symbol name or put your element that inherits from IconElement) but I'm not entirely sure how I can achieve anyting like this.

Code for TemplatedControl

```
[ContentProperty(Name = "Label")]
public sealed class CustomIconButton : Control
{
    public CustomIconButton() => this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(CustomIconButton);

    public IconElement Icon
    {
        get { return (IconElement)GetValue(IconProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IconProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IconProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Icon", typeof(IconElement), typeof(CustomIconButton), new PropertyMetadata(default(IconElement)));

    public string Label
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(LabelProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LabelProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty LabelProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Label", typeof(string), typeof(CustomIconButton), new PropertyMetadata(default(string)));

}
```

Should I do something with *IconProperty* getter or maybe I should override OnApplyTemplate() and do something there?

I'm not sure if it is some feature or something more complex to build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a Templated Control, it will automatically generate an xaml file to store the new control style and template(**Themes folder->Generic.xaml**), you need to add controls to show your icon and text, the values of the IconProperty and LabelProperty you set are ultimately passed to the corresponding property of the controls in the control template.

In order to achieve it, we usually use **TemplateBinding**. Based on the default style of AppBarButton, it uses **ContentPresenter** to bind with the value of its Icon property, we can also do like this. For exmaple:

Generic.xaml:

```
<Style TargetType="local:CustomIconButton" >
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:CustomIconButton">
                <StackPanel>
                    <Viewbox x:Name="ContentViewbox" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonContentHeight}" Margin="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonContentViewboxCollapsedMargin}">
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="Content" Content="{TemplateBinding Icon}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"/>
                    </Viewbox>
                    <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Label}"></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

To use this custom control:

MainPage.xaml:

```
<local:CustomIconButton Icon="Accept" Width="30">hello</local:CustomIconButton>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now I see where I did a mistake in ControlTemplate. I used x:Bind instead of TemplateBinding so symbols weren't showing up in the designer (that should be ovious because of the way x:Bind works :facepalm:). But there's still the part with the Intellisense. Is there a way to make intellisense hint available icons or create your own list?

Comment: Our core control like the AppBarButton has this intellisense since this is done internally, it is by design. It appears this isn't possible on a custom control to add intellisense for your Icon.